# how to modify the right click menu action to be run using admin account?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, context-menu

I'm using [git](https://git-scm.com/) in windows, after installation in File Explorer within any folder, right click, there's a menu "Git Bash Here", which is defined in registry

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git_shell\command
```

, the default key is

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" "--cd=%1".
```

It shows an error

```
error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied
```

that is because I [need need to be in admin mode to execute the command (in cmd terminal or in PowerShell (Admin) on windows10)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56739886/826203).

So what I do now is

1. Right click on Command Prompt, and select "Run as Administrator"
2. In Command Prompt, cd to "C:\Program Files\Git\" Then
3. run "git-bash.exe --cd="d:\git"

This works.

Now, is it possible to modify the right menu option so that this git would be run easily every time as Administrator?

stat result:

```
rliu@ABCD MINGW64 /d/git
$ stat /mingw64/etc/gitconfig
  File: /mingw64/etc/gitconfig
  Size: 377             Blocks: 1          IO Block: 65536  regular file
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (12345678/    rliu)   Gid: (135791/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2019-11-01 18:06:40.256230400 +0000
Modify: 2019-11-01 18:06:40.256230400 +0000
Change: 2019-11-01 18:06:40.257227400 +0000
 Birth: 2019-11-01 18:06:40.255234200 +0000
```

Comment: Do not run git as administrator. What is the output of `stat /mingw64/etc/gitconfig` command. Try to use `chown $USER` and `chmod 644` with that file.

Comment: @Biswapriyo `stat` result updated in the question, what shall i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to answer my own questions in case someone came to the same issue.

this is due to access rights.

there are 2 options

- to run “`git config –**global** core.longpath true`” instead;  to run
- set access right to folder "`C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/`".